# Maximum area of a triangle if distances of the vertices from a point are given

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

Which is the maximum area of the tringle that can be created if we have one point, and we know that its 3 vertices are at a $d_1$, $d_2$ and a $d_3$ units distance from that point. What is the formulae to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Heron's Formula

$$ A = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{4d_1^2d_2^2-(d_1^2+d_2^2-d_3^2)^2}}$$

When is this maximised?